# Having trouble accessing a key in a map inside an []interface

Tags: dictionary, go, interface

**Example code:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    example_container := []interface{}{
        map[string]string{
            "name": "bob",
            "id": "1",
        },
        map[string]string{
            "name": "jim",
            "id": "2",
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", example_container)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", example_container[0])
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", example_container[0]["name"])
}
```

**Problematic line:**

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", example_container[0]["name"])
```

**Error:**

```
invalid operation: example_container[0]["name"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

**Question:**

How do I access the keys inside this interface, then?

Do I have to define a more elaborate interface with a method set to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your slice type is `[]interface{}`, indexing this slice will give you elements of type `interface{}`. Values of type `interface{}` cannot be indexed.

But since you put values of type `map[string]string` into it, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain a value of that map type, which you can index properly:

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", example_container[0].(map[string]string)["name"])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xlRu8Hziqe)):

```
[map[name:bob id:1] map[name:jim id:2]]
map[name:bob id:1]
bob
```

If you know you will always store values of type `map[string]string` in your `example_container` slice, best would be to define it like this:

```
example_container := []map[string]string{
    map[string]string{
        "name": "bob",
        "id":   "1",
    },
    map[string]string{
        "name": "jim",
        "id":   "2",
    },
}
```

And then you don't need type assertion to access the name:

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", example_container[0]["name"])
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rg8hFAf4TR).

Also note that in the composite literal you use to initialize your `example_container` slice, you can even omit the map type when listing the elements:

```
example_container := []map[string]string{
    {
        "name": "bob",
        "id":   "1",
    },
    {
        "name": "jim",
        "id":   "2",
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot. Unfortunately it's a function creating the slice for me which I don't understand yet. I pass in a pointer to my `[]interface` as an argument, and it fills the `[]interface` with maps. At least now I can iterate over them and access the keys.