# How to convert bson.Binary to []byte in Go

Tags: go, bson

I'm writing a small application that receives message in BSON format from network(its not MongoDB) and have to save fields in files on local machine. I'm using gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson for message unmarshaling and it works fine.

Almost everything works except one. There "userdefined" binary field in message and I have to save it to separate file. I tried to use:

```
var pwr = msg["pwr"].([]byte)
```

but got an "error panic: interface conversion: interface is bson.Binary, not []uint8".

Can some one point me an example how to convert bson.Binary to []byte, so I can save it to file.

Comment: If you look at the docs, [`bson.Binary`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Binary) is a struct.

Comment: Yes, it is. But accessing Data field of pwr generate error "pwr.Data undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)" at compile time.

Comment: Which means that `msg` must be a `map[string]interface{}`. Please create a full example, so that we aren't guessing types or context here.

Comment: This question was just posted 5 hours ago, details how to access the wrapped value in an `interface{}`: [Having trouble accessing a key in a map inside an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608942/having-trouble-accessing-a-key-in-a-map-inside-an-interface).

Comment: JimB, sorry, I'm a newbie. I though answer is trivial. icza thanks for a point - it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
pwr := bson.Binary(msg["pwr"].(bson.Binary)).Data
```

But assumes msg["pwr"] can't be anything other than a bson.Binary... if that's not an invariant you should do the type assertion first (handle the possible type mismatch case when it happens) and then cast to get the Data field.